# Webcam no longer works after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, usb, webcam

Webcam no longer works after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

lsusb output for the camera:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05a9:a511 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV511+ Webcam
```

The command:

```
journalctl --follow
```

Produces the following when webcam plugged in:

```
kernel: usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=05a9, idProduct=a511
kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
kernel: gspca_main: ov519-2.14.0 probing 05a9:a511
mtp-probe[15371]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
mtp-probe[15371]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
kernel: input: ov519 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/input/input18
upowerd[2199]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
upowerd[2199]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
```

This camera worked fine on 10.04, 12.04, 14.04 and 16.04.

What am I missing‽

Comment: I feel like this one is maybe related: https://superuser.com/questions/1509544/webcam-is-recognized-but-only-with-low-resolution

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have the same web cam, i did:

`sudo nano /etc/enviroment`

and added:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l2convert.so
```

then rebooted the system and it works with all the programs including the browser.

To turn off the webcam without unplugging do:

```
sudo modprobe -r gspca_ov519
```

To turn it back on do:

```
sudo modprobe gspca_ov519
```

Also make sure you've installed libv4l or v4l-utils and the equivalent 32-bit packages, if you need them.